# Is there a way to simulate "Select all - Copy - Paste" on a webpage in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to extract some data from a webpage. However, if I use the urllib.request module the result is messy since the data is in a html table (not wonderfully done, either).

I found that if I open the page in the browser and simply do CTRL+A, CTRL+C, CTRL+V to notepad - I get exactly what I want. Is there a way to simulate that in python, because there's a large number of pages I need to do that on.

I've also tried using BeautifulSoup, but as I said - the tables are done really badly, it would come down to modifying the code for extracting the text for every table, which would take more time than actually manually copy-pasting.

Comment: The short answer is no... the long answer is using beautifulsoup to slog through the html

Comment: Ok, thanks, that helps. At least I don't have to search for the solution anymore :)

Comment: Another potential library to try is Scrapy (http://scrapy.org/)

Answer (score 1):

There are some alternatives.

- Still using `urllib` but removing HTML tags by yourself or using Beautiful Soup.
- If you're familiar with Qt, use the `QWebKit` module to load the web pages and extract text.
- The [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/) driver to control the web browser.
- If using Windows and portability is not in your plans, you can use the WinAPI (`SendMessage` or `PostMessage`) to simulate <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Selenium is definitely work a shot (WinAPI sounds promising but I don't know). Scrapy might work if there's enough of a pattern to pulling up the pages and drilling down through the tags to the text to extract.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty new to Python, and I don't know what selenium is, but if you can find some kind of pattern, you should be able to do what you described.  The key, is to find a pattern.  Here are a couple sample scripts that may give you some ideas of how to get started . . . .

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

f = open('C:/Users/rshuell001/Desktop/test.txt', 'w')

link = "http://espn.go.com/nba/team/roster/_/name/bkn/brooklyn-nets" 
page = urllib2.urlopen(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")

table = soup.find("table")

for row in table.findAll("tr",{"class":["oddrow","evenrow"]}):
    col = row.findAll('td')

    player = col[1].string
    position = col[2].string

    f.write(player + '\t' + position + '\n')

f.close()


********  ********  ********  ********  ********  ********  ********  ********  ********  ********  


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import urlopen


def make_soup(url):
    html = urlopen(url).read()
    return BeautifulSoup(html)


def get_teams():
    url = "http://espn.go.com/nba/teams"
    soup = make_soup(url)
    teams = []
    for team_chunk in soup.find_all('ul', class_='medium-logos'):
        li_tags = team_chunk.find_all('li')
        for li in li_tags:
            team = li.h5.a
            link = team['href']
            teams.append(link.encode('utf-8'))

    return teams

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print get_teams()
    print len(get_teams())


import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("http://www.kijiji.ca/h-gander/1700255")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
print soup.find_all("a",{"class":"category-selected"})


import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=hardware+engineer&l=San+Francisco%2C+CA"

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

job_titles = soup.find_all("h2", {"class", "jobtitle"})

for job in job_titles:
    print job.text.strip()
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, however, the tables in question have been done really inconsistently, so the moment you dive in HTML the content is unusable.